# Get only from second TR to last from table

Tags: jquery

i have a variable $response and in it i have object of a table

the table has ID

i'm trying to have the variable only with the TR (no TABLE tag or /Table tag) and the TD content

i have tried:

```
$response = $response.find('#gGridView1');
$response = $response.find('tr').slice(1);
```

and

```
$response = $response.find('#gGridView1');
$response = $response.find('tr:first').remove();
```

**i have fixed my first quesiton**

**the answer is:**

```
$response = $response.find('#gGridView1');
$response.find('tr:first').remove();
```

in addition, what would be the way without each or loop to have every TD in the table that is the second column to have a specific width of 100px?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the nth-child selector:

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

So for example, something like:

```
$response.find('td:nth-child(2)').css('width','100px');
```

Comment: so the table i get has P tag inside the TD, IE wont go with it so good, how do i remove all P inside TD without loosing the content?

Comment: Hmm, is it only a <p> tag inside of the tds or are there other elements you want to keep?

You can use .text() in order to get all text inside of an element excluding the HTML tags.  In two steps you could first save the text in a variable and then set it again like so:

`var text = $response.find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
$response.find('td:nth-child(2)').text( text ); `

Comment: without doing it i know it is not the right way... you take every cell and put it in a var, but in the end the var has the last cell in every cell :-) i need something else

Answer (score 0):

To get every tr that is not the first, just select everyone that is not the first:

$response = $response.find("#table tr:not(:first)");

For the second td of every tr use the nth-child selector:

$response = $response.find("#table tr td:nth-child(2)");